# Is it possible to launch music playback from lock screen?

Tags: zune-player

The iPhone allows to start music playback even in a locked state. This is a convenience functionality. Is there something similar for Windows Phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are playing a music and lock the phone you can click the power button to show the lock screen and press one of the volume buttons to show an option to play/pause, forward and rewind the playlist.

I think you can't search and start playing a music in lock screen.